# Assembled human ESTs for annotation

Tags: computational-biology

I am annotating protein-coding genes in a region of the human genome and am looking for a set of assembled ESTs I can use as evidence for constructing gene models. A quick search of NCBI's SRA shows 4,318 human RNA-seq data sets, so I understand there is no shortage of data. I am hoping, however, to save the time that would be required to search through this massive amount of data, select an appropriate subset, and assemble the ESTs myself. I'm sure this has been done many times before, and for this particular task it doesn't make sense to repeat this process.

Is there any sort of general (i.e. not tissue-specific) reference EST/transcriptome assembly available for *Homo sapiens*?

Comment: I would recommend you posting this question on boostar from stack exchange as well.